# errors not showing

Tags: file-upload, php

I have an issue with my php photo upload script. When I upload a file that exceeds 2mb, it won't show that error when I click upload..yet it's there in my script..any idea why this is? For ex. I uploaded a .wma file and It was 2.38MB..that exceeds the limit..but yet it just says "file type not allowed" why didn't it show the exceeds 2mb error as well?

Here is my script:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';

if(!logged_in()){
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

include 'template/header.php';
?>

<h3>Upload Image</h3>

<?php

if(isset($_FILES['image'], $_POST['album_id'])){
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
$image_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image_name)));

$album_id = $_POST['album_id'];

$errors = array();

if (empty($image_name) || empty($album_id)){
    $errors[] = 'Something is missing';
} else {

    if(in_array($image_ext, $allowed_ext) === false){
        $errors[] = 'File type not allowed';
    }

    if($image_size > 2097152){
        $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2MB'; 
    }

    if(album_check($album_id) === false){
        $errors[] = 'Couldn\'t upload to that album';
    }

}

if(!empty($errors)){
    foreach ($errors as $error){
        echo $error, '<br />';
    }
} else {
    // upload image
}
}

$albums = get_albums();

if(empty($albums)){
echo '<p>You don\'t have any albums. <a href="create_album.php">Create an album</a></p>';
} else {
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Choose a file:<br /><input type="file" name="image" /></p>
<p>
Choose an album:<br />
<select name="album_id">
    <?php 
    foreach ($albums as $album){
        echo '<option value="', $album['id'], '">', $album['name'], '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>

<?php
}

include 'template/footer.php';
?>
```

Thanks again for all of the patience with my probably easy posts for a lot of you more experienced programmers out there!
-TechGuy24

Comment: Have you checked that the `$image_size` is being set to the right value? If your server is truncating the upload because of its settings, maybe your file size is coming in below the threshold?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I'm understanding what you mean?

Comment: Try adding `echo $image_size` somewhere in the code, and uploading your WMA file again. It'll show you how large the file actually is when it's being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per code, it should, if uploaded file size is >2mb. However, computers never make mistake but the human and thus debugging is important.

Just replace the code

```
if($image_size > 2097152){
    $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2MB'; 
}
```

with debug statements

```
if($image_size > 2097152){
    echo "in if, image size=".$image_size;
    $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2MB'; 
} else {
    echo "in else, image size=".$image_size;
}
```

This is just a first step of debugging. It may or may not fix the real cause. Let us know the output.

**Edit after comment:**

Put that code in the starting of the file.

```
echo "files<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>imgsz=".$_FILES['image']['size'];
```

What is the output. I guess it might include

```
[error] => 1
```

If it show error=1, Check http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

That mean your upload_max_filesize in php.ini is set to 2MB or less. As soon as person upload file bigger than that, it never reach your code as PHP reject the file by default.

To fix that, open php.ini and increase the limit of upload_max_filesize.

**Edit 3 after comment**

Change

```
if($image_size > 2097152){
```

to

```
if($_FILES['image']['error']==1){
```

That will fix the issue.

Comment: it says now "in else, image size=0 File type not allowed"

Comment: but why is it not seeing the size? it's clearly 2.38mb when I hover over the file before I upload it..

Comment: Sorry I missed that, you want me to add that bit of code to the very top of my script?

Comment: yes. and check what is the value of error. As far as I understand, it must be 1.

Comment: it outputted: "files
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => poem3.wmv
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
imgsz=0
"

Comment: Check edit. That is last edit. Problem must be fixed with that.

Comment: my php.ini. says the max file size is 2mb should I increase it to 3mb?

Comment: Increasing it is not a wise option. Reason is, it will do it globally. Better solution is to check for Error code 1 as I suggested in edit 3 of my reply. Accept the answer, if it works.